# Given asynchronous function, need help trying to write a function to return new time limited version of input function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, timeout

Here are the challenge directions:

Given an asynchronous function fn and a time t in milliseconds, return a new time limited version of the input function. fn takes arguments provided to the time limited function.

The time limited function should follow these rules:

- If the fn completes within the time limit of t milliseconds, the time limited function should resolve with the result.
- If the execution of the fn exceeds the time limit, the time limited function should reject with the string "Time Limit Exceeded".

I've tried these two bits of code:

```
// Function to return new time limited version of input function
const timeLimit = function(fn, t) {

    // Outer asynchronous function
    async function timeLimited(...args) {

        // Set start time to current time
        let startTime = Date.now()

        // Wait to get fulfillment value from function parameter
        const result = await fn(...args);

        // Duration will be current time minus the start time
        let duration = Date.now() - startTime;

        /* If duration is greater than the time parameter,
           throw time limit excession error */
        if (duration > t) throw new Error("Time Limit Exceeded");

        // Else return the result of the await function
        else return result;

    };

    // Return the asynchronous time-limited function
    return timeLimited; };
```

But I get this:

Output:

```
{"rejected":{},"time":100}
```

Expected:

```
{"rejected":"Time Limit Exceeded","time":50}
```

```
// Function·to·return·new·time·limited·version·of·input·function
const timeLimit = function(fn, t) {

    // Boolean to say error is false or true
    let hasError = false;

    // Outer asynchronous function
    async function timeLimited(...args) {

        // Set timer ID
        const timerId = setTimeout(() => hasError = true, t);

        // Constant to hold result
        const result = fn(...args);

        // Clear timeout
        clearTimeOut(timerId);

        // If there is an error, throw it
        if (hasError) throw new Error("Time Limit Exceeded");

        // Else return the result of the await function
        else return result;

    };

    // Return time limited function
    return timeLimited; };
```

But I get this:

Runtime Error

```
(node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ListNode' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `nodejs run --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'TreeNode' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:21) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'NestedInteger' of module exports inside circular dependency
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
Node.js v20.10.0
```

Here are the test cases:

```
const limited = timeLimit((t) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t)), 100);
limited(150).catch(console.log); // "Time Limit Exceeded" at t=100ms
```

If anyone could help me fix my code, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both attempts have some common and some different problems:

The common problems:

- You reject with an `Error` object, while the challenge says that the rejection reason should be a *string*. This is why you see `"rejected":{}` in the output object. So don't do `new  Error`.
- Maybe not an issue, but if the testing framework tests that the `this` argument is passed correctly to `fn`, then this is an issue in your code: it does not pass the `this` argument. To achieve that you should work with `fn.call` or `fn.apply`.

Then to the specific problems:

The first attempt has this issue:

- The promise given as argument to `await` has no knowledge of the time-out and so the async function will only resume when `fn` resolves, which might be well beyond the time-out period. And so the time at which the rejection is triggered is too late. The testing framework detects this time difference.

The second attempt:

- It has a typo in `clearTimeOut`, and so this will immediately trigger a runtime error, which apparently is leading to further unhandled errors in the asynchronous part of the testing code.
- Once that bug is fixed, it will *synchronously* execute both `clearTimeout` and `if (hasError)`. This means the `setTimeout` callback will never run, and even if it did, you already checked `hasError` before it could ever run, and it will always be `false`. Therefore this version of the code will never return a promise that gets rejected with "Time Limit Exceeded".

This kind of time-out behaviour can be implemented with `Promise.race`: you provide it the `fn` promise and a promise that will reject after the time-out. Whichever resolves first will determine the resolution of the promise that `Promise.race` returns.

Here is how that would look:

```js
// Promisified verion of setTimeout:
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Function to return new time limited version of input function
const timeLimit = (fn, t) =>
    function (...args) {
        return Promise.race([
            fn.call(this, ...args), 
            delay(t).then(() => { throw "Time Limit Exceeded"; })
        ]);
    };

(async function main() {
    // Tests
    const fn1 = (n) => delay(1000).then(() => n*n);

    const timed1 = timeLimit(fn1, 1500);
    await timed1(3).then(console.log); // 9

    const timed2 = timeLimit(fn1, 500);
    await timed2(3).catch(console.log); // "Time Limit Exceeded"

    // Your test case
    const limited = timeLimit((t) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t)), 100);
    limited(150).catch(console.log); // "Time Limit Exceeded"
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to create your own custom error message like below:

```
const timeLimit = function (fn, t) {
  async function timeLimited(...args) {
    let startTime = Date.now();
    const result = await fn(...args);
    let duration = Date.now() - startTime;
    if (duration > t) throw new CustomError("Time Limit Exceeded", duration);
    else return result;
  }

  return timeLimited;
};

function CustomError(message, duration) {
  return {
    rejected: new Error(message).message || "",
    duration: duration,
  };
}
```

Comment: No, that is not the problem. I think you misinterpret the fact that the testing framework wraps the output in this `{rejected, duration}` object structure. You can see that the OP's first attempt even has this output. So there is no need to do this yourself. It is not the problem. In the first OP's version the problem can be seen in the different *values* for these two properties.